# Perspective Distortion

Tags: distortion, perspectivecamera, game-maker

I'm making a program where the user clicks 4 corners of a part of a rectangular image. Then the program warps the image so that the 4 corners forming a quadrilateral become a rectangle (right angles). (the full image will no longer be a rectangle) I'm wondering what are the steps (or algorithm) to do this. I've read similar topics about perspective distortion but I'm not sure how to implement them.

At the moment I'm using GameMaker and using [this](http://www.gmlscripts.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=1900) script, but I might change to another language (something similar to C).

tl;dr: User clicks 4 points on image, program warps/distorts image so the 4 points form a rectangle. How?

Edit: (not sure if this will help but) The image is a photo of a rectangular object taken at an angle (so perspective messes around a bit), not just any image with a quadrilateral in it (if it works for all cases then that works too).

Comment: Deforming an image into a quadrilateral can be done by stepping along the *destination* (deformed) axes and interpolating them onto the *source* rectangle. For an aliased method, you can use Bresenham's Line-drawing for this (it does more than drawing lines). But this is **not** the same as a perspective transformation; you first need to decide which one you want.

Comment: I can currently warp the image using the GM script, but I don't know how much to deform it in order for the quadrilateral that the user inputted (4 points) to become a rectangle.

Comment: Pick two opposing corners and set the x and y coordinates of the others equal to these (um.. not *both* of the coordinates. Draw a sketch on a piece of paper and you'll see what I mean.) "Two opposing corners" is easiest if the coordinates are in a regular order -- all clockwise or anti-clockwise --, then you can pick the first and third or second and fourth.

Comment: If by corners you mean the 4 corners the user clicks, how do I distort the image by moving a point inside the image itself? (Currently the script allows me to distort by moving the corners of the entire image)